# Unable to connect with MongoDB remotely from localhost using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect MongoDB Server remotely from localhost but unable to connect. I did like below inside my code:

```
public function connect() {
        require_once 'dbcon/config.php';
        $dbname='koolfeedback';
        $con=new MongoClient('mongodb://10.25.*.*:27017');
        $connect=$con->$dbname;
        $this->db=$connect;
        return $connect;
}
```

I am running my project inside localhost (Xampp). When I was using mongodb locally it was connecting well but now I need to connect to remote server and unable to do that.

Comment: What is the error saying?

Comment: page is not coming at all.and this error `localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500` is coming.

Comment: well, check the logs, something must have stored PHP's error

Answer (score 0):

On the remote mongo server you have to bind your IP or set it **0.0.0.0** . Mongo only listens to localhost by default.

Comment: :check my post.I have already mentioned there the ip still there issue.

Comment: @ anwerjunaid : i have tried also as  per you still issue there.